# How to calculate the angle given a quaternion rotation and a specified axis?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, axis, angle, quaternions

I'm trying to rotate an object around only one axis (any arbitrary unit vector, not necessarily x, y or z), based on the quaternion rotation component along the same axis of a specified quaternion rotation.

```
public void Rotate(Quaternion rotation, Vector3 axis, Vector3 pointToRotateAround)
{
     float angle = ?
     gameObject.transform.RotateAround(pointToRotateAround, axis, angle);
}
```

I don't know how to obtain the angle of my quaternion's rotation that is only along the specified axis. I could do it when the axis is y, for example:

```
public void Rotate(Quaternion rotation, Vector3 pointToRotateAround)
{
     gameObject.transform.RotateAround(pointToRotateAround, Vector3.up, rotation.eulerAngles.y);
}
```

I want to replicate the results of the above, but for any given axis.

I've dug into google trying to find the answer to this but I haven't found a solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a bit more information about how exactly you want to use this and what for. This currently sounds a bit like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/357004). Why do you explicitly need a `Quaternion` as input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I am interpreting your question is that if you have a set of rotating points, by what angle would they move around some other axis.

The only issue with this is that the angle from a different axis actually depends on which point you are looking at.

[image: Rotation]

However, something you could try is to represent your rotation as an axis angle `(ω, θ)`, then take the dot product with your axis `v` to get a new angle of `θ` scaled by `w.v`. This might not be what you want , but if you add details with more details on what you are trying to achieve, we might be able to help you better.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you! It seems so obvious now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I wanted:

```
public void Rotate(Quaternion rotation, Vector3 axis, Vector3 pointToRotateAround)
{
     float angle;
     Vector3 rotAxis;

     rotation.ToAngleAxis(out angle, out rotAxis);

     float angleAroundAxis = Vector3.Dot(rotAxis, axis);

     gameObject.transform.RotateAround(pointToRotateAround, axis, angleAroundAxis);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Then angle of rotation from a unit-quaternion `(w,x,y,z)` also written `w+xi+yj+zk` is `arccos(w)*2`.

If the angle is > 0, the direction is `(x,y,z)/sin( arccos(w)/2 )` otherwise there is no specific direction, and the rotation is identity around any axis; 0 angle is no rotation